# Create an Alert in SQL if a field in a table decreases (Seq number Control Table)

Tags: sql-server, triggers, alert

I have a table where we store our Sequence numbers for jobs and Invoices.
Earlier this week one of the Sequence numbers reset from 100000 odd back to 1.

I would like to create some sort of alert that would inform me if the Sequence number decreases at anytime so that I can proactively resolve the issue then and there.

Table looks like this:

Comp_id - This will always be the same eg. COMP

Seq_type - Name of the Sequence i.e Invoicing

u_version - always '#'

Seq_no - Sequence number that increments when a new invoice is created.

Seq_desc - Definition of the seq_type

SP_str1 - NULL

SP_num1 - NULL

I Need the alert to inform me when SEQ_TYPE decreases its value at anytime.

I am open any suggestions.

Comment: If its not normal such reset to appear, you can add instead of insert/update trigger in order to prevent the change and throw an error. Then, if someone or somewhat tries to edit the column, an error will appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a trigger for the alert:

```
Create trigger trg_u_Sequence on [Sequence]
for update
as 
begin
select [existing].Seq_type as OLDSeq_type, [existing].Seq_no as OLDSeq_no, [new].Seq_type as NEWSeq_type, [new].Seq_no as NEWSeq_no
into #temp
from inserted [new]
inner join deleted [existing]
    on [new].seq_type = [existing].seq_type
where [new].Seq_no <= [existing].seq_type
if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    begin
    --Alert using sp_send_dbmail or write to a table with the contents of #temp
    end
end
```

Comment: just to be clear, the table is a reference table, so no lines are added just the Seq_no updates when new invoices are created then the Seq_no goes from 100 to 101...would you still use for insert? or is there an update trigger?

Comment: @ryall579 I have changed to an update trigger, based on your explanation. If a seq_type has a seq_no go down, it is logged.

Comment: I have tried to use the code you gave me but this just errors when trying to update the table.

Maybe to give you a better idea of what I need.

For instance on this sequence table I want to be able to send me an alert if SEQ_no has reduced in value but to allow for the update to continue as the application that uses this table doesn't error handle very well.

Comment: @ryall579 Are you replacing the commented code ('--Alert using sp_send_dbmail or write to a t') with the alert? Do you have database mail set up? How do you want the alert to be made? It could be written to a table log.